# Get row's distinct count from query result with Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, rowcount

My model query:

```
public function getWorkDays ($id, $month) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(DISTINCT (day)) FROM hours WHERE userid = ? AND month = ?", array($id, $month));
    $row = $query->result();
    return $row[0];
}
```

My view:

```
<p>Total Days: <?php echo var_dump($workDays); ?></p>
```

The error:

> Total Days: object(stdClass)#35 (1) { ["count(DISTINCT (day))"]=> string(1) "9" }

9 should be a correct value but I can't get it with a simple result echo. Also I'm interested why do I have a part of my query at the result obj (["count(DISTINCT (day))"]).

I don't want to use Active record the query should stay like it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, CodeIgniter will return a StdClass Object by default rather than an array, so if you want to use `return $row[0];`, you'll need to use an array returning function.

from [CodeIgniter's Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html):

use `result_array()`

This function returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

you could do something like this:

```
public function getWorkDays ($id, $month){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(DISTINCT day) as workDays FROM hours WHERE userid = ? AND month = ?", array($id, $month));
    $row = $query->result_array();
    return $row[0];
}
```

You also said you wanted a single result, it might even be easier for you to do this:

```
public function getWorkDays ($id, $month){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(DISTINCT day) as workDays FROM hours WHERE userid = ? AND month = ?", array($id, $month));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's for your simple echo...

```
public function getWorkDays ($id, $month){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(DISTINCT day) as workDays FROM hours WHERE userid = ? AND month = ?", array($id, $month));
    $row = $query->row_array();
    return $row['workDays'];
}
```

Comment: Still no joy... Echo result giving notice Array to string conversion

Comment: try a `var_dump();` of the returned value, the functions I suggested DO return arrays, you just need to use the correct key. if you want it to return a specific field, you'll need to use the last code block in my edit

Comment: Tried the return $query->row_array();
var_dump returns Total Days: array(1) { ["count(DISTINCT (day))"]=> string(1) "9" }

Comment: How the part of my query gets to array's key?

Comment: because you didn't designate an alias field in the sql query, use the one I posted and it will work.

Comment: btw I have the last step at my controller. It's             $data['workDays'] = $this->mainpage_model->getWorkDays($user_id, $data['month']);  So the var $workDays at the view should be transferred

Comment: use the very last code block, it will accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yes, it really is! Now what was the point of the last one? Where did he get the key workDays?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59673/discussion-between-kirill-ivanov-and-iamde-coder).