# Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to calculate a value using two variables `$satu_skill_fotografi` and `$jumlah_keahlian_foto`. However, when I try to perform the calculation I get the following error:

> Message: The object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to number

Here is my code:

```php
$satu_keahlian_fotografer = $this->db->query("  SELECT count
                                                FROM tb_nilai_normalize
                                                WHERE term_id = $term[id]
                                                AND fotografer_id = $fotografer[fotografer_id]"); // seleksi satu baru
$nilai_normalize = $satu_keahlian_fotografer / $jumlah_keahlian_foto;

$this->db->query("  UPDATE tb_nilai_normalize
                    SET nilai_normalize = $nilai_normalize
                    WHERE term_id = $term[id]
                    AND fotografer_id = $fotografer[fotografer_id]");
```

The error is thrown on the line:

```php
$nilai_normalize = $satu_keahlian_fotografer / $jumlah_keahlian_foto;
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Hello! This question explains how to get the result from a SELECT COUNT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392152/receiving-the-single-result-with-codeigniter. Hopefully, this will help you to get the result of query to use in your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code line returns the query result as an array of objects. you can do it by row() method which return a single row.

```
$row = $query->row(" SELECT count FROM tb_nilai_normalize WHERE term_id = $term[id] AND fotografer_id = $fotografer[fotografer_id]");

if (isset($row))
{
        echo $row->count;
}
```

For more information you can check the documentation at [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)